# unintentionally declared pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to pass data to a function and write it to an array, but I keep getting an error that states "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char.*'" I understand that char[] is a function and char* is a pointer, but to my knowledge I haven't declared either element as a pointer.

I have two vectors declared:

```
std::vector <char> broken(message.begin(), message.end()); 

std::vector <char> encoded(50);
```

And I am attempting to pass the first vector through a function and add the result to the second function like so:

```
for (index = 0; index <= length - 1; index++)
    {
        encoded[index] = cipher(broken[index], length);
    }
```

With this as the function:

```
char cipher(char broken[], int length)
{
 char index; // declare index

 if( broken[index] < 123 && broken[index] > 96 ) // if characters are lowercase, 
 {                                               // make them uppercase
     broken = broken - 32;
 }

 for(index = 0; index <= length - 1; index ++)
 {
           broken[index] = broken[index] * (2/3); 
           broken[index] = broken[index] - 12;
           broken[index] = broken[index] ^ 2;
 }

 cout << "Message encoded." << endl;

 system ("pause");

 return(broken[index]);
}
```

The error message indicates that the program is receiving one of these elements as a pointer, but I don't know why.

The compiler used is Bloodshed Dev C++ 4.9.9.2. I would appreciate any light anyone can shed on this, as I am a first-time C++ student and quite new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: `cipher` looks like it wanted to be able to iterate through `broken` itself (it will not get far with uninitialized `index`), but you're calling it like it takes a single `char` - read the error message.

Comment: "*I understand that char[] is a function and char** is a pointer" -- What? (and on a side note, does anyone know how to properly put asterisks in comments without italicizing or unitalicizing, and without making it a code block?)

Comment: And you won't make character**s** uppercase with `if`.

Comment: What should I initialize index to though? The textbook I'm working out of for this class acts like the compiler should just know that it points to the index number of the vector, but my compiler insists that I declare it.

Comment: And you add asterisks to posts by placing a \ before the asterisk.

Comment: Your vector is of type `char`, and when you call `cipher(broken[index], length);`, you're passing a single character to your function which requires an array. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you could perhaps make `broken` a vector of arrays instead of a vector of chars.

Edit: But it seems you're trying to make an encoder, so I suppose a vector of arrays might be a little useless

Comment: Dev C++ is an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: Side note: `index <= length - 1` is just weird, prefer `index < length` instead.

Comment: You should talk to your instructor about it, that's why you have him. "I understand that char[] is a function and char* is a pointer" this statement indicates that you just don't really understand enough about the language understand what you need to ask.

Comment: FYI, in `cipher()`, your `for` loop ends when `index` is invalid, but then your `return` uses that `index`.

Answer (score 1):

`char broken[]` says that `broken` is a pointer. That's because, in almost all contexts, the name of an array decays into a pointer to its first element. That's where the compiler is complaining. The function

```
char cipher(char broken[], int length);
```

takes a `char*` and an `int`. It's being called like this:

```
cipher(broken[index], length)
```

which tries to pass a `char` as the first argument, where a `char*` is expected.

Answer (score 1):

What you wanted to write is probably a function which encodes one char:

```
 char cipher(char brokenChar)
{

 if( brokenChar < 123 && brokenChar > 96 ) // if characters are lowercase, 
 {                                               // make them uppercase
     broken = broken - 32;
 }

//there is only one char:
   brokenChar = brokenChar * (2/3); 
   brokenChar = brokenChar - 12;
   brokenChar = brokenChar ^ 2;


 return brokenChar;
}
```

Now you can encode your whole message with a for loop:

```
std::vector <char> encoded(message.size());//maybe there are more than 50 characters

for (index = 0; index <= message.size() - 1; index++)
    {
        encoded[index] = cipher(message[index]);
    }
```

However cipher doesn't do what you expect it to do:

1. `brokenChar = brokenChar * (2/3)` yields always 0 because 2/3 is zero (you could type `brokenChar*2/3` which is probably what you wanted)
2. `brokenChar = brokenChar ^ 2` does not mean `brokenChar*brokenChar` (I assume it is your intention) but bitwise [`xor`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) (promoting brokenChar to `int` by the way), so the cipher would always return -10 no matter what the input is.

And if you ever want to decode your message, your encoding function should be bijective, which it is not even if operations would work as intended

Comment: I've solved all of the other problems of encoding and mathematics, but you're right: the decoding function simply doesn't work. How can I alter the original function to render it bijective so that it can be decoded?

Comment: @Timpanus There are plenty of possibilities: for example one could choose two chars (let's say `sum='h'` and `key='Z'`) and calculate `encoded=(orig+sum)^key`. And than `decoded=(encoded^key)-sum`.